# Hosting for my webservice (for Android/iOS)

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, hosting

I am looking for a new hosting service.
Currently I am hosted in Mochahost in its business PJVM plan.
Can see details in (The middle column):
http://www.mochahost.com/java.php

It works really slow for me. 
Currently most users will be from Israel.

Webservice gives DB services for the application.
Each client post data (shared on the server, MySql DB) (data around 1K max - size of request)
Each client can U/L images (up to 100K size of image).
Each client can request data from the server (response up to 1K).
Each client can D/L images using Http requests.

Besides that nothing is done on the server, client work and when needed - request data from the server.

The Webservice is in Java, with Hibernate as DAL.
MySql is the DB.

Question is - should I upgrade to VPS?
Which hostiing is recommended?
The most important questions - which specifications do I need from the VPS machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going for a VPS will give you full freedom, and choice of VPS depends on cost, location etc factors which you want to go for.

Following are reliable and good in my experience,
Linode
Rackspace
Amazon webservices
prgmr

Mochahost is a shared hosting provider, and shared hosting can have issue with resources (CPU mainly). So i think its a good idea to consider VPS in your case.

Comment: Which specifications should I need for Tomcat?